# Java implementing a FileOpener

Tags: java, image, label, swt

So am trying to make a button where it opens a FileChoser to import an image .

My probleme is :

1-I want the fileChoser to display only images-files(.jpg ...).

2-When the FileOpener opens , the other windows should be Disabled until the 
FileOpener is disposed . In my case , they are disabled but when I click on them my programe crashes for some reason .

3-If there is a better FileOpener it will be welcomed , this si not mine I found it on the net .

Here's my source code :

```
public class FileOpener {

private JFileChooser file_chooser = new JFileChooser();
StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder();

public File choosed() {
    File file = null;
    if(file_chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        file = file_chooser.getSelectedFile();
        Scanner input = null;
        try {
            input = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Fail");
            e.printStackTrace();;
        }

        while(input.hasNext()) {
            path.append(input.nextLine());
        }
        input.close();
    }

    return file;
}

public String getPath() {
    return path.toString();
}
```

}

And here's my call (Where there is a probleme is the enable-disable window) :

```
Button button_2 = new Button(composite_1, SWT.FLAT);
    button_2.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            shell.setEnabled(false);
            FileOpener v = new FileOpener();
            File file = v.choosed();
            if(file != null) {
                Image image = new Image(shell.getDisplay(), file.getPath());
                Image image2 = main.ScaleImage(image, Image_input);
                Image_input.setImage(image2);
            }

            shell.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
```

Notice that this code works , but am trying just to fix the bugs,the "ScaleImage" fonction reScale the chosen Image to fit my label.

Comment: if it works perfectly why are you trying to fix the bugs???

Comment: It works , I fixed it

Comment: JFileChooser is part of the Swing GUI system, for SWT you should use `FileDialog`. Avoid mixing SWT and Swing it will cause you a lot of problems.

Comment: greg-449 , I just tried the FileDialog and it's better then the FileChoser , but I cant get the path for the selected object , is there a source code you can send me ?

Comment: The FileDialog `open` method returns the path of the selected file. There are also `getFileName()` and `getFileNames()` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the Enable-disable problem simply by removing all what was interfering with the shell :

```
Button button_2 = new Button(composite_1, SWT.FLAT);
    button_2.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

            FileOpener v = new FileOpener();
            File file = v.choosed();
            shell.forceActive();
            if(file != null) {
                Image image = new Image(shell.getDisplay(), file.getPath());
                Image image2 = main.ScaleImage(image, Image_input);
                Image_input.setImage(image2);
            }


        }
    });
```

I fixed completly my probleme by using FileDialog :

```
Button button_2 = new Button(composite_1, SWT.FLAT);
    button_2.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

            FileDialog test = new FileDialog(shell);
            test.open();

            File file = new File(test.getFilterPath()+"\\"+test.getFileName());
            if(file != null) {
                Image image = new Image(shell.getDisplay(), file.getPath());
                Image image2 = main.ScaleImage(image, Image_input);
                Image_input.setImage(image2);
            }


        }
    });
```

Thanks for greg-449 for the answer .I didn't know how to exactly work with the new GUI but to get the file path :

```
 test.getFilterPath()+"\\"+test.getFileName()
```